# Dataadaptor returns no values and no exception

Tags: c#, sqldataadapter

i am extreamly stuck from morning can someone help me 
i have a sql data adaptor which is not returning any values . In the same page in the top i have a SQldataadaptor which works fine . I do not know what to do . The query is working fine in the Server. I am using vs10 and sqlserver 2008 ..

I have also tried by removing the parameters  it is still not working '. Always my rowcount is zero

here is my code

```
       doc = dr["DrName"].ToString();
           sql1 = "select w.Day, w.Start,[End] from WeeklyScheduleDays w where w.Start is not null and w.Day = @day1 and  WeeklyScheduleID = (select WeeklyScheduleID from DoctorsBusinessHours db inner join drmast m  on m.DoctorId = db.DcotorID where m.DrName = '@drname2') order by Start ";


           SqlCommand m1 = new SqlCommand(sql1,myConnection);
           m1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@day1", i);
            m1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@drname2", doc);

             SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(m1);
            DataTable t1 = new DataTable();
             ad.Fill(t1);


           rowcount = t1.Rows.Count;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: NO DANGER: No SQL injection! ;-) (I had to +1, because it is so rare!)

Answer (score 1):

Replace `where m.DrName = '@drname2'` with `where m.DrName = @drname2`

Comment: sql1 is just a string and i has a integer value stored in it

Comment: The query does return a set of values in server

Comment: @user2177370: Does it work if you hardcode the values into the query(just for testing purposes)? What sql query does work in ssms?

Comment: So the same sql query that does work in ssms does not work in ADO.NET? That's impossible, there must be a difference. But we don't have the second sight ;)

Comment: select w.Day as day, w.Start as start,[End] as e2 from 
WeeklyScheduleDays w where w.Start is not null and 
w.Day = 2 and  WeeklyScheduleID = 
(select WeeklyScheduleID from DoctorsBusinessHours db inner join drmast m 
 on m.DoctorId = db.DcotorID where m.DrName = 'nurses') order by Start  is my SQL Statement

Comment: @user2177370: That's the working sql in ssms with doesn't work from ado.net?